# Group two character classes together to match maximum allowed characters

Tags: regex

I have the following regex

which allows all alphabet characters besides x, from 1 to 10 characters

`^[a-z][^x]{1,10}$`

However the regex above matches up to 11 characters. How can it be modified to accept only up to 10 characters?

Comment: Do you mean you want to match a string of 1 to 10 ASCII lowercase letters excluding `x`? `^[a-wyz]{1,10}$`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current expression does not do what you think it does. It still matches `x` in the first position and then 10 times not `x` which sums up to 11 characters in total.
That being said, you might be looking for:

```
^(?!.*x)[a-z]{1,10}$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ppjUZF/1).

Answer (score 0):

All alphabets except `x`, from 1 to 10:

```js
^[a-wyzA-WYZ]{1,10}$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/Izncrl/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-wyzA-WYZ]{1,10}       any character of: 'a' to 'w', 'y', 'z',
                           'A' to 'W', 'Y', 'Z' (between 1 and 10
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```